# Navigate back to activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-fragmentactivity

I have class `Demo` and I am extends the demo by `FragmentActivity` class. Also I have another class `Fragment1 extends Fragment`. And the onclick of button i am navigate from activity `Demo` to the Fragment `Fragment1`. Now I want to come back on `Demo` from the `Fragment1`. So how can I back to Demo activity?

Thanks.

Comment: Try harder to explain, because I don't get it. Maybe include some code and show what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking a lot of detail, so I'm taking a stab in the dark here, but...

I presume in your `onClick` code, you use the Fragment Manager to create a new Fragment Transaction, then add the fragment to that transaction and commit it?

Your problem with the activity being closed when you hit the back button is likely because your fragment was not added to something called the "back stack". You can find to documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29, but crucially the main thing you need to do is modify your code to include the line below:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment1());
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("Transaction ID"); // <-- This is key!
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Once that's done, Android will remember the adding of the fragment as a navigation act, and should reverse the transaction when the back button is hit.

---

If this wasn't what you're looking for, or if it doesn't work, please provide some more detail and some code samples and I can take another look.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the fragment you want to go back to manually to the backstack.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
YourFragmentName myFragment = new YourFragmentName();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment);

//if you with to add it to backStack, do this, otherwise skip the line below
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```